# Suppress Blank lines in detail of report

Tags: visual-foxpro

I could find with "suppress blank lines" from "report->page layout->option" under foxpro 2.6 but I'm couldn't be able to find page layout option under report(.FRX) file in visual foxpro 6.

I hope someone could help me on how to suppress excess blank details lines under .FRX file in VFP 6.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of is...  If you have textboxes and/or labels (or lines), if you right-click to bring up the properties of the control.  There should be a tab for "Print When".  You can put in an expression of when you want to print it, by default is always true.  Above that is a checkbox for "Remove line if blank".  If you do this for all controls on a given line in the report, then it SHOULD do what you are looking for.